# Is there a way to get the server-name of the current running vim instance?

Tags: vim

If i want to pass the name of the current running vim-instance/-server to an external script. How do i get it? Apart from `serverlist()` there doesn't seem to be an internal useful function to get direct access to the servername of the running process (=from within the current vim-editor session).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for `v:servername`.

Comment: you can look at this using `:echo` as in `:echo v:servername`

Comment: if you are trying to debug your servers then you might need to look at using the `--remote-silent` option at start up - not using that will cause a new server to be opened

Comment: also for further debugging this page is very useful: I somehow got a server stuck open (I think because of wierd interplay between vim and gvim) http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Close_vim_you_left_open_remotely

Comment: In neovim, you can also use `vim.api.nvim_get_vvar('servername')`

Answer (score 0):

:!hostname

:! escapes to OS shell